# How to bind an event within dynamically loaded content on a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a div inside my html with the id `pageContent`. When users click various buttons, it will load the appropriate content. When a user clicks the javaQuestions button it loads, `javaQuestions.html` into the div just fine. However, inside, the `javaQuestions.html`, I have a collapsible list, and I can't figure out a way to "bind" the li collapse/uncollapse without having the user to click TWICE. Right now what I have is:

```
$("#pageContent").on('click', 'li', function (){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
});
```

So I guess what happens is, first the user clicks on the button, and it loads content. Then, the user clicks on any li, and it enables the "collapsible()" function, but does not uncollapse/collapse the content. Only when the user clicks a second time does it works fine. I tried adding the line `$('.collapsible').collapsible();` into the event that loads the `javaQuestions.html` content, but it doesn't do anything. Kind of at a roadblock, any ideas?

EDIT: Here is the code that loads the content:

```
$("#pageContent").on('click', '#javaQuestions', function (e) {
    fadeIn("#pageContent", "../java-questions/javaQuestions.html", 50);
    fadeIn("#commentsContent", "../comments/comment-section.html", 500);
});
```

I also really want to know how this will function once I figure it out. But as you can see, the above function loads the javaquestions.html, and I can't seem to find a way to ALSO bind 'li' to be collapsible in one swoop.

Comment: can you paste the code that loads `javaQuestions`

Comment: Can you show your code of loading content?

Comment: You can try `$('.collapsible').collapsible().collapsible('expand')` to expand immediately. But hard to tell whether you really want to expand all the collapsibles in the page. Perhaps `$('.collapsible', this).collapsible().collapsible('expand')`?

Comment: I've added a code snippet that show how it loads the content @weigreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using jQuery [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method? You can bind your handler to, say, `body` and then you don't have to care about loading and attaching a handler after it.

Update: may be this will help:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on('click', '#pageContent li', function (){
        $('.collapsible').collapsible();
    });
});
```

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document." I'd much prefer to figure out a way to do this with .on()

Comment: @VDog than see the "Direct and delegated events" in the `.on()` description then (http://api.jquery.com/on/). You just have to attach the handler to an always-present parent (like `body`) and add a selector argument which selects the element which needs event handling (selects among body's children).

Comment: yeah that's what I'm doing for the click function, but how do I use .on for binding an event once the page loaded? Like what keyword do I put in for the eventType

Comment: @VDog so the code I've added a couple minutes ago to the answer doesn't work, too? (try also to put it after the body tag)

Comment: Nah unfortunately. This is what I did at first, but the way it "works" is that the first click, activates the "collapsible" on the li, and every other click including the second click collapses/uncollapses the table as it should :(

Comment: @VDog ah, now I see your point. So there's `collapsed` option (which is also exposed as `data-collapsed` attribute), have you tried that? `$( ".selector" ).collapsible({
  collapsed: false /* or true */
});` You may want to set `data-collapsed` in the beginning so that the state is the one you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Use this DOCUMENT because it is dynamically loaded

```
$(document).on("click","li #pageContent",function(){ 
$('.collapsible').collapsible();
});
```

Comment: I think you meant "#pageContent li", but eitherway, this causes the exact same issue. It works on the SECOND click, because once the user clicks an li, it activates the collapsible method, but I just want that method to run, and bind to li, on page load/when the user clicks on the button that dynamically loads the content.

Comment: I cant understand your problem, i think this will help you https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/

Comment: The problem is : 1) User clicks on a button to dynamically load content. This works perfectly fine. 2) There is a collapsible list in this dynamically loaded content, which needs to be initialized and binded to li, by using the $("collapsible").collapsible(). 3) I don't know how to do step 2, without a binding event like "click", which is what is currently happening. the way it works now is, the user clicks li, the click event linked to li registers this, so then after the first click it works, but I want it to immediately work on the first click.